# Linqpad seemingly does not recognize implemented interface

Tags: interface, linqpad, typeloadexception

I have a c# project GenericBusinessObject and a project WebRole, which uses GenericBusinessObject. WebRole has a BusinessObject Workitem, that implements the Interface method IFastSearchable.IndexDocument that is called from within GenericBusinessObject.
Actually the WorkitemBusinesObject is declared in WebRole as GenericBusinessObject.

I refer both project dlls from LinqPad. But LinqPad fails with an exception.

TypeLoadException: Die Methode "IndexDocument" im Typ "WorkstreamPlatform_WebRole.Models.Workitem" der Assembly "WorkstreamPlatform_WebRole, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" hat keine Implementierung.

LinqPad thinks that Workitem has no implementation of the IndexDocument method. Which is wrong.

Is it a LinqPad bug or am I thinking wrong?

In normal project execution it works.

Answer (score 0):

Usually what I find in these situations with TypeLoadException is that it is related to using different versions of the .NET framework. For example, if you are running version 2.x of LP instead of 4.x while referencing a dll build with 4.x.

I'd look to make sure all versions of the code are compatible. 2.x for LP is 3.5 and 4.x is for 4.0.